# Excel Power Query: Add New Columns by pulling data from other table (Need Solution in Powerquery only)

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am looking for solution only using power query, Because after this solution, i have some more data forming.

[image: Please Refer Image. Click Here]

I have sales table with multiple type of sales units.
I want same sales table with additional columns of transforming units & values to base unit and multiplied values.

Comment: What have you researched / tried, so far? Please [edit] your question to show your code.

Comment: I recently started using power query. I have done lot of stuff in power query but I don't know how to use power query in this case where i have to take reference from another table. 

 I am simply using VLookup in sheet@Table, it is adding automatic Column to table. but I am looking for power query based solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your data needs to be consistent in both your source and conversion tables if you intend to reference the information between the two. You can't use "Rolls" in one and "Roll" in the other to refer to the same thing. Likewise you can't use "Large Box" and "LargeBox" for that purpose. I changed "Rolls" to "Roll" and "LargeBox" to "Large Box." With that said...

Start by loading both tables into PowerQuery. In other words, you'll have two queries: one for your Sales Table and one for your Unit Conversion Matrix. (*When I brought your Sales Table in as a source, I just called it "Sales." I called your Unit Conversion Matrix "UnitConversionMatrix."*)

Select the query for the *Unit Conversion Matrix*, to edit it. You should see something like this.

[image]

You'll need to add your Base Unit to each row, so that it is available later, for the final table. So that's what these next two steps will do.

Click Add Column > Custom Column, and fill out the screen like this:

[image]

...and click OK to see something like this:

[image]

Click on the BaseUnit column to select it, then click Transform > Fill > Down, to get something like this:

[image]

Now you'll shift to your Sales Table. Select the query for your *Sales Table*, to edit it. Once you have it selected, you should see something like this:

[image]

Click Home > Merged Queries, and fill out the screen like this, using whatever name you used for your Unit Conversion Matrix where you see UnitConversionMatrix:

[image]

...and click OK.

Then click the [image] at the top right of the new column that was just added:

[image]

...and set up the dialog box like this:

[image]

...and click OK to see something like this:

[image]

Then click Add Column > Custom Column, and set it up like this:

[image]

...and click OK to see something like this:

[image]

Then you can remove the Value column and move the S.Units2 column to get this:

[image]

Lastly, I think you might have had a math error for your ItmC calculation that yielded 120 for S.Units2. If 1 box = 10 packs and 1 pack = 10 pieces, then 2 boxes should equal 2*(10*10 pieces), which is 200 pieces, right?

Answer (score 0):

Also new to power query in excel so not sure if related. I found after adding new columns to existing queries, I couldn't view the new columns in my append query which appends about 4 queries into one large table. Even after refreshing I couldn't see these new columns. I discovered that if I edit the query, go to the view tab and select the query settings, I can select the settings symbol against the source and as soon as I clicked OK in the subsequent dialog box, all my new columns suddenly appeared in the query.
[image]
Hope this helps someone else who is also blindly navigating something that seems so trivial.